# std::make_unique for GDI+ objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, gdi+

I am trying to use std::unique_ptr for my gdi+ objects due to the benefits of automatic memory management.

Look at this standart gdi+ C style code:

```
Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(image);
graphics->DrawRectangle(/* parameters */); // Working
```

I know that I can use a std::unique_ptr as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics> graphics(Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(image));
graphics->DrawRectangle(/* parameters */); // Working
```

Now I want to construct the std::unique_ptr with std::make_unique but I can't get it to compile.

I have tried the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics> graphics = std::make_unique<Gdiplus::Graphics>(Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(image));
graphics->DrawRectangle(/* parameters */); // Not working
```

But I get the following conversion error:
C2664 Conversion of 1 argument from "Gdiplus::Graphics" in "HDC" is not possible.

I am using the latest version of VS2015.

I thought std::make_unique it should be used like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> varName = std::make_unique<T>(argument with which an instance of T will be constructed);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess that `FromImage` allocates the memory for the `Graphics` object, and if this is the case you won't need `make_unique`.

Comment: Another note: Make sure that the `Graphics` object allocated are ment to be deallocated using `delete`, e.g. `delete graphics;`. Otherwise you need to use a custom deleter for your `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `std::make_unique<T>(args...)` calls `T::T(args...)` (with proper forwardng). So in your case you are calling `Gdiplus::Graphics` constructor with type `Gdiplus::Graphics*`, which is not your desire. You don't want make unique here. But you can create your own function, which shortens a syntax a bit.

```
std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics> make_graphics(/*whatever image is*/ image)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Graphics>(Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(image));
}
```

Also, as [gurka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/969365/gurka) mentioned in the comments, once `std::unique_ptr` gets out of scope, it's content is destroyed using `delete` operator. IF `Gdiplus::Graphics*` has to be destroyed using custom deallocation method, you have to provide it to `std::unique_ptr` constructor (like `std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(destroy_T)>(arg, destroy_T)`

Answer (score 0):

> I thought std::make_unique it should be used like this:
>
> ```
> std::unique_ptr<T> varName = std::make_unique<T>(argument with which an instance of T will be constructed);
> ```

Yes

> What am I doing wrong?

You are not constructing a instance. You're calling a function which constructs a instance for you, so it is not possible to use `std::make_unique` here.